# How to change/visit a map instance's value through map pointer in Go?

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

Assume we have code:

```
var Cache_map *map[string]int

Cache_map = new(map[string]int)
```

Then we want to add key: `type` & value `1` into `Cache_map`, how shall we do?

Comment: I don't know why people treat this question useless, it might be useful in some situation. Just a different view of Golang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really need to do that, for example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var Cache_map *map[string]int
    Cache_map = new(map[string]int)
    *Cache_map = make(map[string]int)
    (*Cache_map)["type"] = 1
    fmt.Println(*Cache_map)
}
```

Output:

```
map[type:1]
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for `new`, `make` or a pointer to map in this case. Skeleton/example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var CacheMap = map[string]int{}

func main() {
        CacheMap["type"] = 1
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", CacheMap)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2uXk6H4VdS)

---

Output:

```
map[string]int{"type":1}
```

Comment: I just wonder how to implement that? Certainly I have given a very simple example but in more complicated cases map pointer might be needed.

Comment: @ReckHou: Map is a reference type. Actually it's already implemented as a pointer to some run time data structure. Passing around the reference (the RT data pointer) is enough to share the map from more than one place in your program.

Comment: OK, I know it's useless now.